Django Custom Dynamic urlpatterns
I'm working on a django project and in this project I have two subprojects. So in this case what I want to do is store domains and assign services (my subprojects) to these domains.
For example, let's say I have service1 and service2. And in my domains table I store:
service1.domain.com -> service1
domainforservice1.com -> service1
service2.domain.com -> service2
domainforservice2.com -> service2

something like this. So in this case I'm struggling with some issues, because I want to control the domain that request made and according to that domain I can find which service I should load on the main path. So basically we want to make this control:
if domain.service = service1:
    urlpatterns += path('', service1.urls)
if domain.service = service2:
    urlpatterns += path('', service2.urls)

But the problem is as we can't take the domain in this area from request we can't make this control. I have tried to write middleware for this and I get the domain address in request.domain but again we have the problem because middleware is executed before this urls.py file. So in this case I'm stuck and can't find a solution to resolve this problem.

Isn't it something to be done using a reverse proxy server such as Nginx or Apache? You can have two Django projects running on two different ports and route the requests conditionally to the appropriate Django server, using a config file

django support multiple site with sites framework.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/sites/
# site1 settings.py
SITE_ID = 1
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [aaa.com]

$ python manage.py runserver --settings={site1.settings}

# site2 settings.py
SITE_ID = 2
ALLOWED_HOSTS = [bbb.com]

$ python manage.py runserver --settings={site2.settings}

and
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site
from django.http import Http404
def my_view(request):
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    if current_site.domain == "foo.com":
        # Do something
    else:
        raise Http404

or
# views.py
from django.conf import settings
from django.http import Http404
def some_view(request, *args):
  if settings.SITE_ID == 3:
    # do something
  else:
    raise Http404

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/contrib/sites/#hooking-into-the-current-site-from-views

So far a good answer but make it complete by answering this part of the question: "… I want to control the domain that request [?is] made and according to that domain I can find which service I should load on the main path".
